# SwipeRefreshLayout overlaps BottomAppbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I feel like I've tried everything to resolve this but I can't figure out how to have a Coordinatorlayout containing an bottom app bar and a constraintlayout that contains a swipe refreshlayout without the refresh layout overlapping the bottom app bar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".departures.DeparturesActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        tools:context=".departures.DeparturesActivity">

        <RelativeLayout-with-some-stuff-in-it/>

        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/departures_swiperefresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/departures_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/md_keylines"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/md_keylines" />

        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/departures_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:tint="@color/colorWhite" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="end"
        app:fabCradleMargin="4dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="16dp"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="4dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The SwipeRefreshLayout will overlap the bottom app bar and I cant quite figure out why.

[image]

Part of the problem is the fact that the UI designer seems to indicate that the constraintlayout expands way below the coordinatorLayout.

[image]

This is due of the padding added here to push the layout below the actionbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".departures.DeparturesPresenter">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: screenshots would be better to understand

Comment: added a screenshot now.

Comment: try to add margin bottom to ConstraintLayout like this `android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize30dp"`

Comment: But there must be a better way?

Comment: Sorry, I should have typed `android: layout_marginBottom = "?Attr/actionBarSize" `

Comment: Still there must be a better way to get the coordinateLayout and constraintlayout to respect each other rather than adding margins?

Comment: @adipurnama that didnt make any difference btw.

Comment: i'm try use constraintlayout v1.1.3 and i'm add to constrainlayout `android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"` then at SwipeRefreshLayout change `android:layout_height="match_parent"` then at recycleView change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and it work,i hope this help bro

Comment: and at `<RelativeLayout-with-some-stuff-in-it/>` i'm get warning `element is not allowed here`

Comment: It's a relativeLayout I redacted out. I can replace it with any arbitrary view with a hardcoded or dynamic height and the problem persists.