# RecyclerView in ConstraintLayout always overlays bottom if other nested views are added

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I've never been able to figure out how to get  recyclerview properly constrained in the bottom if any other view is above the recycleView. There must be something trivial I'm missing because this is pretty maddening.

The following layout looks fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".alerts.AlertsActivity">

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/alerts_swiperefresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/alerts_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/md_keylines" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, let's add a View with a fixed height above the recycleview.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:context=".alerts.AlertsActivity">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#20000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/alerts_swiperefresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/alerts_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/md_keylines"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/md_keylines" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, the recyclerview is no longer properly constrained in the bottom and the bottom item is out of sight or partially cut off. The designer also indicates that the bottom of the recyclerview is out of bounds below the screen.

If I replace the Constraintlayout with a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout it looks just fine.

The difference is easily visualized from the designer view.

[image: correct constraints]
[image: incorrect constraints]

Comment: Where is your bottom items in layout. Add your full layout

Comment: I mean the items in the list adapter assigned to the recyclerview.

Comment: just an idea from a quick glance: did you try adding 
 a bottom constraint to the swipeRefreshLayout? 

app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

Comment: also setting: android:clipToPadding=false on the RecyclerView

Comment: You haven't bound the swipe refresh layout to the bottom of the parent. you also haven't bound it to the left or the right of the parent...

Comment: With android:layout_width="match_parent" I assumed I didnt have to constraint it horizontally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add bottom `constraint` to your `SwipeRefreshLayout`

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/alerts_swiperefresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top">
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work. What threw me off is that I initially had the ConstraintLayout wrapped in a CoordinatorLayout and doing the same thing with the RecyclerView there broke the entire layout. Any suggestions on how to resolve that issue?

Comment: If you add layout, then i can check

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59591995/swiperefreshlayout-overlaps-bottomappbar?noredirect=1#comment105360569_59591995